# setContentview() change layout in onConfigurationChanged() but not set the Data in android

Tags: android, xml, orientation, landscape, portrait

I have created two layouts for portrait and landscape mode, My scenario is I want to change the Text of TextView based on the orientation changes. here is my code:-

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

activity_main.xml (portrait)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.demo.textdemo.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

activity_main.xml (landscape):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.demo.textdemo.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    />
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textViewHello;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);
    Configuration newConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION LANDSCAPE");
    }else {

        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION PORTRAIT");
    }

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION LANDSCAPE");

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION PORTRAIT");
    }
}
```

}

For the First Time, it shows the change in TextView according to the Orientation but when I change the Orientation it shows "Hello World!" , which define in activity_main.xml, I don't know why ??

Answer (score 1):

I have found the Solution. I need to convert the XML object into Java Object when orientation change, because if orientation change layout will also change and so it will need to convert XML into Java Object.

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);
        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION LANDSCAPE");

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);
        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION PORTRAIT");
    }
```

thanks @Dhanumjay

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textViewHello;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

textViewHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);
textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION PORTRAIT");

}
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION LANDSCAPE");

} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION PORTRAIT");
}
}
```

Comment: I already try this, but this doesn't change the design it only set the Text, for landscape set background to RED and for portrait YELLOW you see the difference it doesn't change the Layout when orientation change.

Comment: for changing background you need to write programatically  in activity.

Comment: I want to change TextView value based on orientation changes and design need to be changed (background is just I give an example to you that design does not change when I write your code)

Comment: You can change design based on your requirement but you need to give same reference id's in both layouts

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Just remove this line from manifest file then everything working fine

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Comment: But in this case, every time orientation change Activity is destroyed and recreated which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change manifest file and try below code.Now its working fine without recreating Activity

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    textViewHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION LANDSCAPE");

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textViewHello.setText("ORIENTATION PORTRAIT");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android whenever you want to set data regarding configuration changed you have to call two override method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}
```

Comment: yes, we use these methods, but in that case, Activity is Destroy which I don't want.thanks for answering.